# How to avoid using user profile to perform s3 operations without EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

According to many advices, we should not configure `IAM USER` but using `IAM Role` instead to avoid someone managed to grab the user confidential in `.aws` folder.

Lets say I don't have any `EC2 instances`. Can I still able to perform `S3` operation via `AWS CLI`? Says `aws s3 ls`

> MacBook-Air:~ user$ aws s3 ls
>   Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that, when running applications on Amazon EC2 instances or as AWS Lambda functions, an **IAM role** should be assigned that will provide credentials via the EC2 metadata service.

If you are *not* running on EC2/Lambda, then the normal practice is to use **IAM User** credentials that have been created specifically for your application, with least possible privilege assigned.

You should **never store the IAM User credentials in an application** -- there have been many cases of people accidentally saving such files into GitHub, and bad actors grab the credentials and have access to your account.

You could store the credentials in a **configuration file** (eg via `aws configure`) and keep that file outside your codebase. However, there are still risks associated with storing the credentials in a file.

A safer option is to provide the credentials via **environment variables**, since they can be defined through a login profile and will never be included in the application code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use [service roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html) on your personal machine.

You can however use [**multi-factor authentication for AWS CLI**](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use credentials on any machine not just EC2.

Follow the steps as described by the documentation for your OS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am trying to avoid using user credentials but wanted to use role instead

Comment: You can attach a role to IAM User and take it from there. You can attach Roles only to IAM Users or AWS Resources. Not to any external resources.